# softROCE RDMA same device on different ports

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rdma

I was wondering if there is a way to create rdma rxe devices with the same device name, but different ports. Essentially, the same RDMA device but with different ports, over different eth interfaces.

When I do something like

```
$ sudo rdma link add rdma_1 type rxe netdev ens3
```

It would create an RDMA device named `rdma_1`, over eth interface `ens3`.

Now I cannot create another device with the same name, over some other eth interface

```
$ sudo rdma link add rdma_1 type rxe netdev ens4
error: Too many open files in system
```

Is there a way to do this. What I essentially need is a configuration like this,

```
$ ibstatus
Infiniband device 'rdma_1' port 1 status:
    default gid:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:5054:00ff:fe12:4313
    base lid:    0x0
    sm lid:  0x0
    state:       4: ACTIVE
    phys state:  5: LinkUp
    rate:        2.5 Gb/sec (1X SDR)
    link_layer:  Ethernet

Infiniband device 'rdma_1' port 2 status:
    default gid:     fe80:0000:0000:0000:5054:00ff:fe12:4314
    base lid:    ...
    sm lid:  ...
    state:       4: ACTIVE
    phys state:  5: LinkUp
    rate:        2.5 Gb/sec (1X SDR)
    link_layer:  Ethernet
```

Comment: Why not create multiple RDMA devices for the different netdevs?

Comment: @haggai_e One can do that. But thats not my use case. I need to have the same device with different ports. Sort of a multipath I suppose.

Comment: AFAIK RoCE doesn't support APM, so I'm not sure how multipath would work. Perhaps you could try to create a layer 2 teaming device and use rxe on top of that.

Comment: @haggai_e Can you elaborate whats APM, and how it affects multipath.

Comment: APM stands for automatic path migration, which is a mechanism that allows connected QPs to switch to an alternative path upon failure on their primary path.

Comment: @haggai_e Thanks. Do you have any information about how to create this teaming device?

Comment: There's a guide for RedHat [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configure_a_network_team_using-the_command_line). To be honest, I haven't tried it, so I don't know if rxe works over teaming, but I don't see why it shouldn't.

Comment: @haggai_e Thanks.. Will take a look.